# Symfony Dynamic Form : Expected argument of type "string", "NULL" given at property path "civilite"

Tags: symfony4, symfony-forms

I try to code a Dynamic form to edit a user.

There is a zipCode (codePostal) inside. If someone change a zipCode it should change the cities list (communes).
I use dynamics forms recommended by Symfony. This works very well for my RegisterForm, but not for this editForm.

I think, i miss something to get the informations from the user ? 
So every time i change the zipcode, it is not able to get the dynamic form and create this exception in my console (ajax) : Expected argument of type "string", "NULL" given at property path "civilite".

This exception is generated on the $form->handleRequest($request); of my controller, but just when i change the zipcode, not at the first loading of the form.

This is my code :

```php
//Form/EditUserFormType.php

class EditUserFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $user = $options['data'];

        $builder
            ->add('civilite',ChoiceType::class, array(
                'choices' => array('M.' => '1', 'Mme'  => '2'),
                'required' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => false,
                'data' => $user->getCivilite()
            ))
            ->add('nom')
            ->add('prenom')
            ->add('societe')
            ->add('telephone')
            ->add('adresse')


            ->add("codePostalAutoComplete", TextType::class, [
                "mapped"=>false, 
                'required' => false,
                "label"=>"Code postal",
                ])

            ->add('codePostal', EntityType::class, [
                'class'       => 'App\Entity\CodePostal',
                'placeholder' => ''/

            ])

            ->add('email');

        $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, CodePostal $codePostal = null) {
            $communes = null === $codePostal ? [] : $codePostal->getCommunes();

            $form->add('commune', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => 'App\Entity\Commune',
                'placeholder' => 'Choisir une commune',
                'choices' => $communes,  
            ]); 
        };




        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                // this would be your entity, i.e. SportMeetup
                $data = $event->getData();

                $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getCodePostal());
            }
        );




        $builder->get('codePostal')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {

                $codePostal = $event->getForm()->getData();


                $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $codePostal);
            }
        );
} 



    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

```php
//Controller/AccountController.php

public function edit(Request $request): Response
    {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $form = $this->createForm(EditUserFormType::class,$user);



        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();       
                $em->persist($user);
                $em->flush();

                $this->addFlash('notice', 'Vos modifications on bien été prises en compte !');

                return $this->redirectToRoute('app_account_dashboard');

        }

        return $this->render('account/edit.html.twig', array(
            'user' => $user,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

```html
//templates/account/edit.html.twig

{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}


{% block stylesheets %}

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var $codePostalAutoComplete = $('#edit_user_form_codePostalAutoComplete');
            var $codePostal = $('#edit_user_form_codePostal');

            $codePostalAutoComplete.change(function () {

                $newValue = $codePostalAutoComplete.val();
                $('#edit_user_form_codePostal option').filter(function () {
                    return($(this).text() == $newValue); // To select Blue
                }).prop('selected', true);

                // ... retrieve the corresponding form.
                var $form = $(this).closest('form');
                // Simulate form data, but only include the selected codepostal value.
                console.log($form); 
                var data = {};
                data[$codePostal.attr('name')] = $codePostal.val();
                // Submit data via AJAX to the form's action path.
                $.ajax({
                    url: $form.attr('action'),
                    type: $form.attr('method'),
                    data: data,
                    success: function (html) { // Replace current position field ...
                        $('#edit_user_form_commune').replaceWith(
                            // ... with the returned one from the AJAX response.
                                $(html).find('#edit_user_form_commune')
                        );
                        // Position field now displays the appropriate positions.
                    }
                });
            })


        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}

{% block title %}Modifier mon compte
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

    <h1>Modifier mon compte</h1>

    {{ form_start(form) }}

    {{ form_row(form.civilite) }}
    {{ form_row(form.nom) }}
    {{ form_row(form.prenom) }}
    {{ form_row(form.societe) }}
    {{ form_row(form.adresse) }}
    {{ form_row(form.codePostalAutoComplete) }}
    <div style="none;">{{ form_row(form.codePostal) }}</div>
    {{ form_row(form.commune) }}
    {{ form_row(form.telephone) }}
    {{ form_row(form.email) }}
</p>


<button class="btn" type="submit">Valider</button>
{{ form_end(form) }}{% endblock %}
```

Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: If you are going to submit just one field, you need a different controller method to retrieve the dynamic values, you can't use the form action. See [this symfonycast](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-forms/dynamic-select-js).

Comment: Thanks, i follow your advices and what they explain on symfonycast and found the way. Have a great day msg ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @msg said in the comment, i made a need to use an other controller to get just the subform i needed;

```php
//AccountController.php


public function editCommunesFieldByCodePostal(Request $request, CodePostalRepository $codePostalRepository)
    {
        $codePostal = $codePostalRepository->find($request->query->get('codePostalId'));

        if (isset($codePostal)){


            $user = new User();
            $user->setCodePostal($codePostal);

            $form = $this->createForm(EditUserFormType::class, $user);

            //dump($form);
            //die();

            if (!$form->has('user')) {
                return new Response(null, 204);
            }
            return $this->render('account/_specific_commune.html.twig', [
                'form' => $form->createView(),
            ]);
        }
    }
```

```html
//account/edit.html.twig


{% block body %}

    <h1>Modifier mon compte</h1>

    {{ form_start(form) }}

    {{ form_row(form.civilite) }}
    {{ form_row(form.nom) }}
    {{ form_row(form.prenom) }}
    {{ form_row(form.societe) }}
    {{ form_row(form.adresse) }}
    {{ form_row(form.codePostalAutoComplete) }}
    <div style="display:none;">
    {{ form_row(form.codePostal, {
                attr: {
                    'data-specific-location-url': path('app_account_edit_communes_by_codepostal'),
                    'class': 'js-user-form-codePostal'
                }
            }) }}
    </div>

    <div class="js-specific-commune-target">
        {%  if form.commune is defined %}
            {{ form_row(form.commune, {
                attr: {
                    'class': 'js-user-form-commune'
                }
            }) }}
     {% endif %}
    </div>

    {{ form_row(form.telephone) }}
    {{ form_row(form.email) }}
</p>


<button class="btn" type="submit">Valider</button>
{{ form_end(form) }}


{% endblock %}


{% block javascripts %}
{{ parent() }}
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {




    $('#edit_user_form_codePostalAutoComplete').on('change', function(e) {


        $newValue = $('#edit_user_form_codePostalAutoComplete').val();
        $('#edit_user_form_codePostal option').filter(function() { 
            return ($(this).text() == $newValue); //To select Blue
        }).prop('selected', true);


        var $codePostalSelect = $('.js-user-form-codePostal');
        var $specificLocationTarget = $('.js-specific-commune-target');


            $.ajax({
                url: $codePostalSelect.data('specific-location-url'),
                data: {
                    codePostalId: $codePostalSelect.val()
                },
                success: function (html) {
                    if (!html) {
                        $specificLocationTarget.find('select').remove();
                        $specificLocationTarget.addClass('d-none');
                        return;
                    }
                    // Replace the current field and show
                    $specificLocationTarget
                        .html(html)
                        .removeClass('d-none')
                }
            });

    });
});
</script>

{% endblock %}
```